# Using the Split tool on a single polyline with strange results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, splitting

I am having issues with the Split tool.  When I try and split a line at a given point my result is not  a new feature where the break was meant to occur.

This is my line (one feature)
[image]

This is where I place the cursor for the split to happen.
[image]

The result is two lines but they are not as expected....I want one line North of where I put the split tool and another South of where I put the split tool....instead I have a small segment of line two in the middle of line one.
[image]

Has anyone seen this before or know what I might need to change in order for this split to work as I want it to?

Comment: Is there an issue with scale? Have you tried zooming in closer to the line and splitting? Also, please edit your question with the version of ArcGIS you are using.

Comment: Sorry using 10.5.1 As it turns out my one feature polyline was actually made up of many lines that did not connect.....hence the unexpected result.  Thanks for the follow up though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your linear feature is a "multipart feature". Try using the "Exploding MultiPart Feature" tool before splitting your line. You'll be able to find this tool in the "Advanced Editing" toolbar.

> You can use Explode Explode Multipart Feature on the Advanced Editing
>   toolbar to separate a selected multipart feature into its individual,
>   component features. This would be useful if you needed to alter the
>   attributes of one of the elements in a multipart feature.

See more information [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/separating-a-multipart-feature.htm) on multipart features.

Comment: Thank you sir!!!  That is what I was missing....one record but it is a MultiPart feature...who knew.